# Can I see boot screen on vagrant up?

Tags: vagrant

For default if you starting vagrant (with vagrant up) then you can only see Vagrant messages. How can I print out boot informations from the box I'm just booting with?

EDIT: I want to test some init scripts and see how they behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that command prompt? Not easily. What you can do is get the vm provider to run in headed mode so you can see the virtualised console, e.g. for virtualbox add:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  # Don't boot with headless mode
  vb.gui = true
end
```

Indise the `Vagrant.configure` block.

Comment: That's cool, but I can't scroll back (with CTRL-up) to the beginning on boot screen. It seems it because the default buffer limit. How can I change it?

Comment: Not sure. vm.provider allows you to pass fairly arbitary opts as I recall, so figure out what the parameter to pass to vboxmanage would be and try that.